# Dragging mouse on an image, showing another image underneath

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, mouseevent

I'm a beginner with writing code so I'm struggling a bit with this one.
I want to have two images layered on top of each other, and when you use your mouse on it like dragging or painting, the image underneath will show in the places you've traced. 
I've been using these as source, but none of them use an image on top and I haven't been able to replace the top layer with an image:

https://rifke.world

https://codepen.io/uargh/pen/eYmoXgJ
I think I'll probably need `ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";` but I'm not too sure how to apply it to an image

Any help would be very appreciated since I've been fighting with this for a while.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sure! Sorry it's all over the place with things I've tried and also there're probably some code which doesn't serve any purpose since I was trying to tweak found code. Also the background image is a mosaic, which I don't really want to but haven't been able to fix it yet https://codepen.io/rociprocal/pen/mdeBqJg

Comment: Please adjust the question to provide a[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see anywhere that you are loading a second image, I think you should do something like:

```
var img2=new Image();
img2.onload=function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img2,0,0);
};
img2.src="http://placekitten.com/700/1023";
```

I tried it [here](https://codepen.io/dovolopor/pen/ExVbWJx), looks like this achieves what you are trying to do.

Besides, you can use PageX and PageY instead of ClientX and ClientY, so that your code works as expected when page is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a static image and a canvas element, pretty much what the link you included is doing. Here's the code from that site to dig into further how they are updating the canvas element for that effect. https://rifke.world//js/script.js?ver=1.4.

You can draw the image you want on top on the canvas element using the following method https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp.